# Incorrect syntax near SqlParameter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, syntax, sqlparameter

I have this code

```
Dim q = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ddddd] WHERE ([Day] >= %XX ) AND ([Day] <= %YY )")
q.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("XX", rangeFrom.Value))
q.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("YY", rangeTo.Value))

q.Connection = dbc

Dim rd = q.ExecuteReader()
' ...
```

It throws a `SqlException` on the

```
Dim rd = q.ExecuteReader()
```

line with message

> Incorrect syntax near 'XX'

Why?

Comment: what are the `%` signs for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server parameters need to be prefixed with a `@` (not a `%` as you've used it):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [ddddd] 
WHERE [Day] >= @XX AND [Day] <= @YY
```

and then also use the leading `@` when declaring the parameters:

```
q.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@XX", rangeFrom.Value))
q.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@YY", rangeTo.Value))
```